# Is it possible to inject a script by a Safari extension without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

We created extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. When the extension gets upgraded, we want to inject a script to Gmail, which asks the user to refresh. But the problem is, in Safari this script only gets injected after the user reloads the page. Is there a way to inject the script immediately?

Here is our code:

```
this.inject_show_notification_script = function() {
    var possible_urls = /^([^\/\?]*\/){2}([^\.\/\?]+\.)*(mail\.google\.com)\//gi;
    var possible_urls_array = [
        "http://mail.google.com/*",
        "https://mail.google.com/*"
    ];
    var possible_urls_script_url = utils.get_url("content/src/common/show_notification_script.js");
    var possible_urls_script_relative_url = utils.get_relative_url("content/src/common/show_notification_script.js");
    switch (platform) {
        case 'chrome':
            chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
                for (var i in tabs) {
                    if (tabs[i].url.match(possible_urls) !== null) {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {
                            file: possible_urls_script_relative_url
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'safari':
            safari.extension.addContentScriptFromURL(possible_urls_script_url, possible_urls_array, [], true);
            break;

        case 'firefox':
            for (var i in tabs) {
                if (tabs[i].url.match(possible_urls) !== null) {
                    tabs[i].attach({
                        contentScriptFile: possible_urls_script_url
                    });
                }
            }
            break;
    }
};

this.disable_inject_show_notification_script = function() {
    // This is only needed in Safari.
    var possible_urls_script_url = utils.get_url("content/src/common/show_notification_script.js");
    switch (platform) {
        case 'safari':
            safari.extension.removeContentScript(possible_urls_script_url);
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumning that when a Safari extension gets updated, its global page (if any) will reload with the new content — this is true, if I remember correctly — you could have some code in the global page that checks all open tabs to see if any of them are Gmail tabs. Then the global page could put up an alert advising the user to reload these tabs. For that matter, you could potentially reload these tabs yourself, although that might not be polite.

If you want to use something fancier than a standard alert, perhaps you could send a message to the affected tabs to tell them to display some fancy HTML message. But I'm not sure if the injected scripts will pay attention to messages coming from an updated global page; it would be interesting to find out.